# Frequency of entire table in SAS

Tags: sas, frequency

Is it possible to get the frequency of an entire table in SAS? For example I want to count how many yes's or no's are in an entire table? Thanks

Comment: Are there multiple columns with `Y` and `N` values ?  Are the values coded as `1` means `Y` and `0` means `N`

Comment: There are multiple columns with the same categories,string values.

Answer (score 2):

A `hash` component object has keys and can track `.FIND` references in key summary variable specified with the `keysum:` tag attribute supplied at instantiation.  The `keysum` variable, when incremented by `1` per `suminc:` variable will compute a frequency count.

```
data have;
  * Words array from Abstract;
  * "How Do I Love Hash Tables? Let Me Count The Ways!";
  * by Judy Loren, Health Dialog Analytic Solutions;
  * SGF 2008 - Beyond the Basics;
  * https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings/pdfs/sgf2008/029-2008.pdf;

  array words(17) $10 _temporary_ (
    'I' 'love' 'hash' 'tables'
    'You' 'will' 'too' 'after' 'you' 'see'
    'what' 'they' 'can' 'do' '--' 'Judy' 'Loren'
  );


  call streaminit(123);
  do row = 1 to 127;
    attrib  RESPONSE1-RESPONSE20 length = $10;
    array RESPONSE RESPONSE1-RESPONSE20;
    do over RESPONSE;
      RESPONSE = words(rand('integer', 1, dim(words)));
    end;
    output;
  end;
run;

data _null_;
  set have;

  if _n_ = 1 then do;
    length term $10;
    call missing (term);
    retain one 1;
    retain count 0;

    declare hash bins(suminc:'one', keysum:'count');
    bins.defineKey('term');
    bins.defineData('term');
    bins.defineDone();
  end;

  set have end=lastrow;
  array response response1-response20;

  do over response;
    if bins.find(key:response) ne 0 then do;
      bins.add(key:response, data:response, data:1);
    end;
  end;

  if lastrow;

  bins.output(dataset:'all_freq');
run;
```

[image: Frequency Table]

---

Original answer, presumed only Yes and No

Yes.  You can array values, compute as 0/1 flag for each No/Yes value and then use SUM to count 0's and 1's.  SUM computes FREQ only when dealing with just 0's and 1's.

Example:

```
data have;
  call streaminit(123);
  do row = 1 to 100;
    attrib  ANSWER1-ANSWER20 length = $3;
    array ANSWER ANSWER1-ANSWER20;
    do over ANSWER; ANSWER = ifc(rand('uniform') > 0.15,'Yes','No'); end;
    output;
  end;
run;

data want(keep=freq_1 freq_0);
  set have end=lastrow;
  array ANSWER ANSWER1-ANSWER20;
  array X(20) _temporary_;

  do over ANSWER; x(_I_) = ANSWER = 'Yes'; end;

  freq_1          + sum (of X(*));
  freq_0 + dim(X) - sum (of X(*));

  if lastrow;
run;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that. Unfortunately I was only using yes/no as an example. I actual want to count the frequency of around 30 different values.

Comment: You can use a HASH object to perform complex custom frequency computation.  Will update.

Comment: do over is technically deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Transpose your main data and then do a proc freq. This is fully dynamic and scales if the number of question scales or the responses scale. You do need to have all variables be of the same type though - character or numeric.

```
*generate fake data;
data have;
call streaminit(99);
array q(30) q1-q30;

do i=1 to 100;
do j=1 to dim(q);
q(j) = rand('bernoulli', 0.8);
end;
output;
end;

run;

*flip it to a long format;
proc transpose data=have out=long;
by I;
var q1-q30;
run;

*get the summaries needed;
proc freq data=long;
table col1;
run;
```

You should get output as follows:

```
The FREQ Procedure

COL1    Frequency   Percent Cumulative
Frequency   Cumulative
Percent
0   581 19.37   581 19.37
1   2419    80.63   3000    100.00
```